# Why is a linked list faster than Vector in AS3?

Tags: performance, actionscript-3, actionscript, avm2, flash-10

I tried the benchmark on this site: [Array vs. Vector vs. Linked list](http://wonderfl.net/c/zKzb/). It tests the performance of iterating over said sequences.

Remarkably, iterating over a linked list is approximately **2.5x faster** than a `Vector.<int>`. What is the reason for this counter-intuitive result?

Comment: I got these results today (01 Dec 2012) Array: 13000
Vector: 1031
Linked list: 1828

Answer (score 1):

Bounds checking and the indexing function call could be contributing a large chunk of the inefficiency.